# Does Task.WhenAll run Tasks in background thread parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Are the following 2 code fragments do the same?

```
//--------------------------------------------------
1.
//--------------------------------------------------

var producer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await bar.ReadDataAsync();
});

var consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await bar.WriteDataAsync();
});


await Task.WhenAll(consumer, producer);

//--------------------------------------------------
2.
//--------------------------------------------------

await Task.WhenAll(bar.ReadDataAsync(), bar.WriteDataAsync());
```

Comment: yes.. both already running tasks execute in parallel and then result combined after waitall call.

Comment: Well not really the same. 1.) creates four tasks + 1 for WhenAll. 2.) creates two tasks + 1 for WhenAll.

Comment: But will method 2 not run the both tasks in current thread basically competing for schedule time?

Comment: BTW, about example (1), assuming ReadDataAsync and WriteDataAsync return `Task` (and not just any awaitable), you don't need to wrap them in `Task.Run()`.  `var producer  = bar.ReadDataAsync()` is enough and makes more sense **in most cases**.

Answer (score 6):

`Task.WhenAll` does not run the tasks. No tasks are started by this method.

What `Task.WhenAll` *does* do is return a new `Task` that only completes **when all** the original tasks have completed.

From msdn

> ### Task.WhenAll Method
>
> **.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5**
>
> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your example, you have called `Task.Run`. This is a request that you would like to run a unit of work asynchronously. However, the thread affinity is not guaranteed. Both units of work may run synchronously - that is up to the default `TaskScheduler` to decide.

Comment: "Both units of work may run synchronously" - Thats what i figured with my test. So basically the second version does not spin up 2 background threads and run them true multithreaded.

Comment: @rudimenter async io calls are the truest form of parallelism - they do not spin up threads because thry do not require threads. Arguably, the first version is needlessly using background threads.

Answer (score -5):

There's no magic in `Task.WhenAll` - it's a method like any other.

As such, first all its arguments are evaluated, and only after that the method itself is executed. So yeah, you get parallel execution.